# How can cnosdb support a meta cluster connecting to multiple data clusters?

Tags: cnosdb

I found the `cluster_name` option in both the data and mate configurations, which should be used to distinguish different clusters, but I failed to connect two clusters to the same meta, and the `cluster_name` in the meta configuration only supports a single value and does not support multi-value configuration. Can this feature be implemented at present?